# Average Delay in networking

Tags: network

There is an example in web caching section 2.2.5 in the book "computer networking a top down approach".Can anyone explain me the example?
How average delay became 0.4*0.01 + 0.6*2.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a weighted average of 40% requests with .01 s and 60% requests with 2.01 s response time.

Comment: Does it mean that each request at cache has a delay of 0.01 seconds and each request at server has a delay of 2.01 seconds?

Comment: Yes. The text is quite explicit on that.